# Баг функции удаления элемента

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть функция, которая должна обновлять массив пользовательских данных удаляя из него элемент. По onClik в функциональный элемент передаётся ссылка на метод и на индекс элемента в массиве. Всё до этого момента работает корректно (проверял `console.log()`). Есть странная особенность метода `splice()`. Вроде как тут прочёл описание ( 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice ), но всё работает не так. Я не совсем понимаю почему.
При вводе:

```
1;
2;
3;
2;
```

И нажатии на 3 консолит это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
deleteNote (index) {
    let arr = this.state.lies;
    console.log(arr);  //
    arr = arr.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(arr);  //
    this.setState({lies : arr});
}



render () {
    let lies = this.state.lies.map( (item, index) => {
    return item = <NewLi 
                text = {item.text}
                key = {item.id}
                id = {index}
                deleteNote = {this.deleteNote.bind(this)}
                />;
    })



function NewLi (props) {
return(
    <div>
        <li>{props.text}</li> 
        <button onClick = {() => props.deleteNote(props.id)}> X </button>
    </div>
    );
} 
module.exports = NewLi;
```

Comment: Что не так? В консоли все верно тебе выдает, .splice()  возвращает ссылку на массив с удаленными элементами

Comment: Так я хочу 1 элемент удалить, а функция удаляет все, кроме того по которому был клик.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замени arr = arr.splice(index, 1) на arr.splice(index, 1) и будет счастье.

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто уже часов 6 сижу, разбираюсь. Вот, тупить начал.)

Comment: @Evander , не за что))У всех бывает))